# Use of undeclared identifier C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, allegro5

I’ve been learning C++ recently and I’ve been trying to create a simple class split into a header & a source file. However, I seem to keep on getting this error:

```
ship.cpp:21:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'image'
        return image;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

I've included the source code below:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>

#include <ship.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = nullptr;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = nullptr;


    if(!al_init()){
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialise allegro", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    if(!al_init_image_addon()) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialize al_init_image_addon!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    display = al_create_display(800,600);
      if(!display) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialize display!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return 0;
      }


    Ship ship("image.jpg");
    al_draw_bitmap(ship.get_image(), 200, 200, 0);

    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(2);
    return 0;
}
```

**ship.h:**

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>

class Ship
{
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image;

    private:
        int width;
        int height;

    public:
        Ship(std::string image_file);
        ALLEGRO_BITMAP *get_image();
};

#endif
```

**ship.cpp:**

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <ship.h>




Ship::Ship(std::string image_file){
    image = al_load_bitmap(image_file.c_str());
    if(image == nullptr){
        std::cout << "Ship went down." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Ship loaded successfully." << std::endl;
}   


ALLEGRO_BITMAP *get_image(){
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined the function incorrectly. `get_image()` is a member of the `Ship` class. Your definition creates a standalone function.

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *get_image(){
```

Should be:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* Ship::get_image(){
```

(asterisk repositioned for readability)

Comment: Oh, didn't spot that. Thanks! Btw, is it convention to place the asterisk with the return type as this improves readability? i.e. `ALLEGRO_BITMAP*` as opposed to `ALLEGRO_BITMAP *`?

Comment: It's really just a style thing. I prefer to put the asterisk on the left when it's the return value of a function but on the right when it's a variable declaration or dereference.

Answer (score 1):

As it's currently defined, `get_image()` is just a function that has nothing to do with your class. The fact that it's located in `ship.cpp` is inconsequential. Since you're trying to implement a **method** of the `Ship` class, you need to defined the implementation with the `Ship::` prefix:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* Ship::get_image() {
    return image;
}
```